# Making Z axis stack correctly

Tags: html, css, z-index

On the following page http://blackburndigital.co.uk/boxes.html I'm trying to position the number (strong) over the black box (lense) on the z axis, so that the number (strong) is initially visible.

Here is the html

```
<div class="fact">
<div class="lense"></div>
<strong>4</strong>
<p> Years in business   </p>
</div>
```

and the css (with some values removed for simplicity... view source code on the link above for full css)

```
.fact 
{background:red; 
overflow: hidden; 
position: relative; }

.fact strong 
{ display: block;
position: relative;
 z-index: 10;}

.lense {width: 200%; 
height: 100%;
 z-index: 5; 
position: relative;}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong... any ideas?

Comment: Looking at it quickly the z-index of the .fact strong is much lower than .lense, which is above it. Also, the number currently only appear when you hover. If you want them to so initially what do wan to be happening on the hover?

Comment: I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kUaNs/) for you and done something with it, although I'm not quite sure of what you want to achieve..